# Pass a value from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes, actionlistener, jtextpane

I am trying to get a value from my Calculator (which is in its own separate class) to the `JTextPane` in my other class.  My only concern is that I am not able to do so because of the design of my program.

In my main class I have an inner class that opens up another frame when the `JMenuItem` is clicked.

---

```
public class Notepad extends JFrame
{
    ...
    // Opens when the user clicks Calculator 
    // (JMenuItem in the JFrame of the Notepad class)
    private class Calculator implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Calculate c = new Calculate();
            c.buildGUI();

            // I've tried creating a reference to the Insert class and tried to
            // retrieve the value from the JLabel in the Calculator but continuously
            // receive a NullPointerException
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

And in my other class I have an inner class for the Insert button (which allows the user to insert their answer into the `JTextPane` if they wish).

***I've tried many things here such as creating a "getter" and "setter" that passes the value onto the Notepad class but have discovered that they don't work due to the setup of my program.

---

```
public class Calculate extends JFrame
{
    ...
    /* Insert
     * Inserts the answer into the 
     * text pane of the Notepad class
     */
    private class Insert implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String answer = proposal.getText(); // from the JLabel
            if (answer.isEmpty()) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Enter two numbers and hit the desired operator, please");
            // else, insert the answer
            // ***
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Another one of my problems is that when the `JMenuItem` (Calculator) in the frame for my Notepad is clicked I receive a `NullPointerException` because there is no value in the `JLabel` (Answer for the calculator).

So how do I grab the value of the `JLabel` from the Calculator and put it into the `JTextPane` of my Notepad frame when Insert is clicked?  Also if my program is not setup to perform such an action, do you have any re-design suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to pass a reference to the NotePad into the Calculator class. The Calculator class will then look like this:

```
  public class Calculator extends JFrame{

         Notepad notepad;

         public Caluclator(Notepad np){
             this();
             notepad = np;
             //any other code you need in your constructor
         }

         ...

         private class Insert implements ActionListener
         {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
              String answer = proposal.getText(); // from the JLabel
                if (answer.isEmpty()) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Enter two numbers and hit the desired operator, please");
                else{
                     notepad.myJTextPane.setText(answer);
                }
            // ***
         }


}
```

And to call it in the Notepad class:

```
   Calculate c = new Calculate(Notepad.this);
```

Having said that, it would be a good idea to look up some design patterns such as [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which are precisely for updating one class when another is changed.

Comment: I'm sure you were in a rush to write this answer, because the code won't compile and you violated naming conventions. The variable `np` is local to the `Calculator` constructor. So what I'm trying to say is, change `>np.**myJTextPane**.setText(answer);` to `notepad.**myJTextPane**.setText(answer);` Other than that, nice answer! +1

Comment: Thank you very much!  The only thing that I want to point out is the `this();`... should it be `this.notepad = np`?  And yes, excellent answer!

Comment: @Mike No, that isn't neccessary. If the `Notepad` variable used in the `Calculator` constructor were named `notepad` then yes, you would use `this.notepad = notepad`.

Comment: @fireshadow52 Really?  I tried using what Vincent suggested (`this();`) and received some errors.  The `this.notepad = np` is working quite well.

Comment: @Mike Oops! I misunderstood what you were asking. I'm sorry. No, don't use `this()`. Calling `this()` calls the constructor again. But, you aren't passing any argumuments to the constructor (which is what the constructor needs) and that is why you are getting an error. Even if you put an argument in `this()`, it would be stuck forever in an infinite loop (which I'm sure you don't want). So no, you don't need `this()`

Comment: @Mike I included the call to this() because you did not have a constructor in your example and I was hoping to imply that you continue doing whatever you were doing with your constructor such as calling super() etc. If you do not have a no-argument constructor then leave out the call to this().